# Selector to resize views

Tags: android, android-view, android-selector

Let's say I want to give the user the ability to resize a view by presenting a white rectangle with dots in the corners which he can drag around. The resizing itself is pretty easy but my problem is the rectangle.

If I place it exactly at the edges of the view then one-quarter of the dots will be cut off. By adding some margin or padding to the target two view next to each other will be pushed away from each other... Also, according to the material design guidelines, a touch target should be 48dp but my dots shouldn't fill that whole space.

So how should I do this? Is all of this possible with a selector or do you need a helper view for this? Also, how would something like this work in a Recaclerview where I can resize items?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear.. Try adding some code or images to better depict the problem you are facing with

Comment: Can you add an image or a code?

Comment: Try making a view containing dots in the corners and resizable view part in the center with some margins. Margins will provide space for those dots.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly.

In your xml file where the dots are add this to a view that is a parent for the dots:

```xml
<ParentViewWhatever
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <DotView ... />

    <DotView ... />

    <DotView ... />

</ParentViewWhatEver>
```

or in code:

```
parentViewWhatever.clipChildren = false
parentViewWhatever.clipToPadding = false
```

This way your dots won't be cut off.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first having an operation that "enables" this feature (eg. getting focus, a long-press, or a menu item), then use a ViewOverlay to draw on top of the view the user is editing. The overlay can be as simple or complex as desired and will site on top of the view being edited.

Once the editing is finished (perhaps by losing focus, another log press, or via a menu item), just hide/remove the view overlay.

You should be able to create a general purpose View to display your rectangles etc and use it on multiple controls if desired.

By adopting this approach you don't make your app "messy" all the time, and you give clear UI signals to the user.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good :) When I use a ViewGroupOverlay I should be able to handle onClick events for the views inside that overlay right?

Comment: It's just another view, with all the rules that apply to sub views. Main thing is it lies on top of the host view, so can be used to trap events etc

Comment: So, have you adopted this solution?